# How to fill HTML view from controller response

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, view

Create a normal HTML page as view and access the values using the **forms-collection** in the action, get all the forms values. It's work perfectly,
but stuck on edit view, How to fill edit view as like following HTML page/view.

**Html view for saving and edit**

```
<div class="hideDiv current" id="DemographicsDetail" style="display: block;">

    <div class="form-group" id="'1'">
        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control input-medium" name="1" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="" required="">
    </div>   

    <div class="form-group" id="'6'">
        <label class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>&nbsp;(<small style="font-style:italic">mm//dd/yyyy</small>)
        <input class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium date-picker" name="6" size="16" type="date" value="" required="">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="'4'">
        <label class="'control-label">Height</label>&nbsp;(<small style="font-style:italic">Inches</small>)
        <input class="form-control input-medium decimalonly" name="4" placeholder="Inches" type="number" value="" required="" data-original-title="" title="">
    </div>

       <div class="form-group" id="395">
        <label class="control-label text-primary" style="font-weight: bold;"></label><br>
        <label class="control-label">Company Name</label><br>

        <select class="form-control input-medium" id="Test_395_Company_Name__c42fc5d4-58da-408b-a2d6-9c4f0a312631__395" name="Test_395_Company Name_[c42fc5d4-58da-408b-a2d6-9c4f0a312631].395">
            <option value="">-- Select--</option>
            <option value="229">Progressive Physical Therapy -Congaree</option>
            <option value="231">Progressive Physical Therapy</option>
            <option value="233">Progressive Physical Therapy -Congaree</option>
            <option value="234">Progressive Physical Therapy -Simpsonville</option>
            <option value="235">Progressive Physical Therapy -Hillcrest</option>
        </select>
    </div>    
</div>
```

How to fill HTML view from controller response?

Comment: It's the same as reading the data, but the other way around. Why don't you [Add a model to a Razor Pages app in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: @rickvdbosch, thanks for your reply, I know how to use the model with a view, but At this moment I need to bind data in view without the model.

Comment: If you were able to write some javascript to get data from inputs and send it to a backend, it shouldn't be too hard to write some javascript that gets data from a backend and puts it into inputs, right? What have you tried, and where did you fail? Please give us some relevant code.